# Footer navigation menu

Tags: menus, add-menu-page

Our website is https://de.ferberg.com and we are a manufacturer of warehouse equipment and mobile loading ramps. On our site the navigation menu is added to the footer via code and theme editor, it is duplicated from the main menu in the header, but we need to add elements there that are not in the main menu. We tried adding through the menu editor, but no new display areas are available in the theme. Can you tell me how to add a new menu display area in Wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

you can add new menu from WordPress admin on this https://de.ferberg.com/wp-admin/nav-menus.php?action=edit&menu=0 and then you need to call this menu where you're calling your footer menu.